# Faster way to prove that two elements do not belong to the same H-coset?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

**Q:**
Let $H$ be the of subgroup $S_5$ consisting of those permutations that fix the letters 5 and 1. For each of the following pairs of elements of $S_5$, determine whether or not they belong to the same left $H$-coset.
$$f_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\3 & 2 & 5 & 4 &1\end{pmatrix},\;g_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\1 & 2 & 5 &3 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$
Do $f_1$ and $g_1$ belong to the same left $H$-coset?

---

**My answer:**
$$$$
Since 5 and 1 are fixed, $H=\{(234),(243)\}$. To show that these two elements are part of the same $H$-cosets, I can show that they are of the same equivalence class (because a subgroup is partitioned by a disjoint union of equivalence classes, $g_1\sim_L f_1$, which occurs $\iff g_1f_1\in H$.

try: $g_1f_1=(453)(135)=(413)\notin H\implies g_1 \not\sim_L f_1$

Did I answer this question correctly, and furthermore, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It is not true that $g_1 \sim_L f_1$ iff $g_1 f_1 \in H$. What is true is that $g_1 \sim_L f_1$ iff $g_1 H = f_1 H$ (here the class $gH$ is defined by $gH = \{gh \mid h \in H\}$). This is equivalent to say that there are elements $h_1,h_2 \in H$ such that $g_1 h_1 = f_1 h_2$, or $f_1^{-1} g_1 = h_2 h_1^{-1} \in H$, which in turn is equivalent to say that $f_1^{-1} g_1 \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

The $H$ you define is a subgroup of $S_{5}$, but the elements you list for it do not form a subgroup. The correct $H$ is (isomorphic to) the group of permutations of $\{ 2, 3, 4 \}$, so it is isomorphic to $S_{3}$, of order $6$. But as you'll see in the following, to solve your exercise it is not necessary to spell out the elements of $H$.

As noted in a comment, your condition for $f_{1}, g_{1}$ to be in the same left coset is incorrect, the right one being $g_{1}^{-1} f_{1} \in H$ (or equivalently $f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} \in H$).

Now $f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} \in H$ iff $1  f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} = 1$ and $5  f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} = 5$. Just check whether these hold true.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "of", as in $H < S_5$, and not $H=S_5$

Comment: My first sentence was unclear, I have edited it.

Comment: May I please ask where $f_1^{-1}g_1\in  \iff 1f_1^{-1}g_1=1$ came from/what's the motivation behind checking this statement? As I understand it, we're using $f_1^{-1}g_1$ to permute 1 and 5, but am confused why we can compose a permutation with an element of the set {1,2,3,4,5} (and not another permutation).

Comment: The correct statement is $f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} \in H$ iff $1  f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} = 1$ **and** $5  f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} = 5$, and this is how you defined $H$.

Comment: I apologise, but I fundamentally do not understand how $1f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} = 1$ and $5f_{1}^{-1} g_{1} = 5$ work. With my current understanding of how permutations work, I can take any two permutations $k$ and $p$ on some set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ and compose the permutations to get another permutation $kp$. Hence, I am unsure what the notation $5f_{1}^{-1} g_{1}$ represents; how can a single element of the set (5—a number) be multiplied/composed with a "permutation $f_{1}^{-1} g_{1}$ (a function)"?

Comment: Sorry, it is matter of notation, then. To me $1 f_{1}^{-1} g_{1}$ is the value of the permutation  $f_{1}^{-1} g_{1}$ on the element $1$. For instance, $1 f_{1} = 3$ and $1 g_{1} = 1$..

Comment: viz, if I am not mistaken, I can simply check whether or not "1" and "5" are fixed in the composed permutation of $f_1^{-1}g_1$ from the equivalence criterion?, i.e., whether or its cycle notation contains 1 and 5?

Comment: Yes, just check whether $f_{1}^{-1} g_{1}$ fixes **both** $1$ and $5$. You do not even need to compute the whole $f_{1}^{-1} g_{1}$ for that.